# Facing error in loading image using Glide: Can't call reconfigure() on a recycled bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, transform, android-glide

I am getting error

> Can't call reconfigure() on a recycled bitmap

while loading image using Glide library. 1 out of 5 time I am getting this error. Image size is around 1.5MB.

I am using version 3.8.0 of Glide.

**Here is my code for Transformation:**

```
public class ScaleToFitWidthHeightTransform extends BitmapTransformation {
int mSize = AppConstants.HEIGHT_TRANSFORM_LIMIT; //1020  
boolean isHeightScale;

public ScaleToFitWidthHeightTransform(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    float scale;
    int newSize;
    int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();
    int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();

    // If original bitmap height/width is less then the height/width transform limit
    // then no need to scale the bitmap, so return the original bitmap
    if (sourceHeight < AppConstants.HEIGHT_TRANSFORM_LIMIT && sourceWidth < AppConstants.WIDTH_TRANSFORM_LIMIT) { // Height and width limit is 1020.
        return source;
    }
    Bitmap scalBitmap;

    if (sourceHeight > sourceWidth) {
        scale = (float) AppConstants.HEIGHT_TRANSFORM_LIMIT / source.getHeight();
        newSize = Math.round(source.getWidth() * scale);
        scaleBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, newSize, mSize, true);
    } else {
        scale = (float) AppConstants.WIDTH_TRANSFORM_LIMIT / source.getWidth();
        newSize = Math.round(source.getHeight() * scale);
        scaleBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, mSize, newSize, true);
    }
    if (scaleBitmap != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }

    return scaleBitmap;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
    return  transform(toTransform);
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return "com.abc";
}
```

**Here are the lines where I am using Glide**

```
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageUri).asBitmap()
                .transform(new ScaleToFitWidthHeightTransform(context))
                .placeholder(defaultDrawable)
                .error(defaultDrawable)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        BitmapSourceData bitmapSourceData = null;
                        bitmapSourceData = new BitmapSourceData();
                         bitmapSourceData.setBitmapSource(getBitmapBytes(resource));

                        if (imageView != null) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        }                           
                 }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                            super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                            Log.e("ABC", "Exception --> " + e.toString());
                }); // Here I am getting error printed.
```

I searched on net. It says it is due to using recycled bitmap but I am not able to fix it.
So what's the wrong one I am doing.?

Answer (score 0):

You have recycled the bitmap here..

```
if (scaleBitmap != source) {
    source.recycle();
}
```

Don't do this..

Also createScaledBitmap is a very heavy operation, avoid using it. You can scale a bitmap using canvas and matrix..

Comment: If I don't recycle unwanted bitmap, it may create memory out of flow exception.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to recycle the bitmap. just watch your reference count. if there rae no more references to the bitmap the GC will aggessively kick in and clean it up for you. this is just a flag that it can be GC sooner.

from bitmap docs about recycle method:

> /**
>        * Free the native object associated with this bitmap, and clear the
>        * reference to the pixel data. This will not free the pixel data synchronously;
>        * it simply allows it to be garbage collected if there are no other references.
>        * The bitmap is marked as "dead", meaning it will throw an exception if
>        * getPixels() or setPixels() is called, and will draw nothing. This operation
>        * cannot be reversed, so it should only be called if you are sure there are no
>        * further uses for the bitmap. This is an advanced call, and normally need
>        * not be called, since the normal GC process will free up this memory when
>        * there are no more references to this bitmap.